# How to create complex ListView with grouped items?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I'm trying to create ListView adapter for grouped contents. I cannot use just multiple types of list items, because I've got complex design(image is not real design, but the layout):

[image]

You can see from image, that there are list item views inside group view. And group view has set background for whole group, not just for its header. Therefore I cannot use `ExpandableListView` either:
[image: http://www.mobiledevguide.com/2012/09/how-to-work-with-android.html].

Is it possible somehow possible to implement that design using few inflated elements, and on-demand content population for these elements like `ListView` does?

Or do I need to implement whole widget on my own? I've took quick look at `ListView` sources. It is almost 4k LOC!

I know, that something similar is possible using hack: 3 types of list items: `header`, `item`, `last_item_of_group`. And fake background of group using these different items `(header,item,item,item,last,header,item,item,...)`, but I can't do that now!

Comment: I don't understand, why can't you do what you describe in the last part of your question?

Comment: Because background of whole view is not just color. It's more complex, therefore I can't split it over few items.

Comment: What's the size of each group, and how complex is it? I've had a ListView with complex entries (each entry was about 0.8~3 screen heights) implemented by LinearLayout that contains a bunch sub-layout (wasn't proud of it). It ran OK on Galaxy Nexus & Nexus One, albeit with slight stutter right before showing a new entry. You might want to test that out before trying more complex engineering solution.

Comment: @Kai Gonna try that solution. Maybe once write custom widget, and new type of adapter for it.

Comment: Also, if each child's height is fixed, you can just inflat an empty view in the first pass, and then fill out the content in subsequent screen refresh.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using Expandable Listview. 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html

Comment: How do I set widget for group? Not just for group header!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the MergeAdapter, I had done a similar view as the one you desire.

https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-merge